# How to load and use XML file hosted in Github

Tags: javascript, xml, github

The code below is working, but when I change the relative path location of the XML file `activities.xml` to an absolute file from Gitbub `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Podatus/web-files/master/activities.xml` it did not work, I have this error :

> TypeError: Argument 1 of XSLTProcessor.transformToFragment is not an object.

looks like he cannot load XML

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename){
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
  else {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
  try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
  xhttp.send("");
  return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult(xslFileName){
  xml = loadXMLDoc("activities.xml");
  xsl = loadXMLDoc(xslFileName);
  // code for IE
  if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
    ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
    document.getElementById("showData").innerHTML = ex;
    }
  // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
  else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
    xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    var temp = document.getElementById("showData") ;
    while(temp.firstChild){ // delete all ancient data
      temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild);
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
    }
    document.getElementById("showData").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

Comment: Absolute path to what? File system? Server path? Error messages in console?

Comment: You would have to use an absolute URL e.g. `http://example.com/foo.xml` or `file:///C:/Users/johndoe/foo.xml` but in general, inside the browser, the same origin policy might prevent any access to an origin other than the one the original document hosting the script has been loaded from.

Comment: thanks, the error do not come from the path but from the way I used the server Github ... I am not sure I can use the raw.githubusercontent.com to load XML

Comment: What I want to do seems possible with **gist.github.com***. indeed [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/b3ff6ae1c120eea654b5) uses some files hosted on gist.github and display them. I have tried [here](http://maxence.larrieu.free.fr/temp/activities.html)  but I have an _CORS  Access-Control-Allow-Origin_ error ... any idea ?